# openssl: how to disable "writing RSA key" message in console

Tags: bash, shell, openssl

Is there any way to disable console message "writing RSA key"?

```
$ openssl rsa -pubout -outform DER -inform PEM -in /tmp/res/chrome.pem -out 1 > /dev/null 
writing RSA key
$ openssl rsa -pubout -outform DER -inform PEM -in /tmp/res/chrome.pem -out 1
writing RSA key
$ openssl rsa -pubout -outform DER -inform PEM -in /tmp/res/chrome.pem > /dev/null
writing RSA key
```

I tried those commands, with same result :(

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Running the command with `strace` shows that the message is written to `STDERR`:

```
write(2, "writing RSA key\n", 16)       = 16
      ^
```

so you have to redirect `STDERR` instead of `STDOUT`:

```
openssl rsa -pubout ... 2>/dev/null
```